# InstancePerRequest DbContext ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Registering DbContext in ASP.NET MVC Application as `InstancePerRequest`. (`IoC Autofac`)

```
builder.RegisterType<ADbContext>().As<IADbContext>().InstancePerRequest();
```

Using inside `BService`

```
public class BService : IBService
{
    readonly IADbContext _dbContext;
    public BService(IADbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }
}
```

Trying to register `IBService` as Singleton.

```
builder.RegisterType<BService>().As<IBService>().SingleInstance();
```

Obviously, this gives me an error

> No scope with a tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the scope in which the instance was requested.

Simplest solution is to register `IBService` as `InstancePerRequest`, but there is no reason having PerRequest `IBService` rather than error message mentioned above.

How can i use `PerRequest` `DbContext` inside Singleton service ?

Comment: Short answer: you can't. You would have to inject the context into the singleton for every request. Honestly, this feels like a code smell, perhaps you need to rethink your setup?

Comment: @DavidG Probably, could you suggest best practice ?

Comment: I don't think it's about best practice here, but I do think if you are messing with a context, then a singleton is probably not a good idea. Contexts need to be created as late as possible and destroyed as quickly as possible. Also, they do not support concurrency, you will get some weird errors if 2 requests try to hit it at the same time.

Comment: @DavidG Thanks, so use PerRequest services ? or having some `Factory` class which will return new context everytime requested ?

Comment: I guess that depends on your use case. Generally I go with services per request unless they are expensive to create (which is very rare)

Answer (score 1):

First attempt, you can inject IContainer into BService. But this will look like Service locator pattern, which is not good. Otherwise, you can define factory interface

```
public interface IFactory<T>
{
    T GetInstance();
}
```

Then implement it and register

```
public class SimpleFactory<T> : IFactory<T>
{
    private IContainer _container;

    public SimpleFactory(IContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;     
    }

    public T GetInstance()
    {
        return _container.Resolve<T>();
    }
}

public class DbContextFactory : SimpleFactory<IADbContext>
{   
    public DbContextFactory(IContainer container):base(container)
    {   
    }
}
```

Finally, use this factory in your singletone

```
public class BService : IBService
{
    IADbContext _dbContext =>  _dbContextFactory.GetInstance();
    IFactory<IADbContext> _dbContextFactory

    public BService(IFactory<IADbContext> dbContextFactory)
    {
        _dbContextFactory = dbContextFactory;
    }
}
```

Each time, when you want to acess to context inside singletone, it will pass this request to IoC container, which able to return context per request.